# B-topological ring that is not semi-topological?

Tags: gn.general-topology, ra.rings-and-algebras

> A topological space $A$ that is also a ring with operations ‘$+$’ and ‘$.$’, is a semi-topological ring if the mappings
> \begin{gather*}
> a_1: A\times A \to A\text{ such that }(x,y)\to x+y, \\
> a_2: A \to A\text{ such that }x\to -x
> \end{gather*}
> and $$a_3: A \to A\text{ such that }(x,y) \to x.y$$ are semi-continuous where  $ A\times A$  carries product topology.

> A topological space $A$ that is also a ring with operations ‘$+$’ and ‘$.$’, is a B-topological ring if the mappings \begin{gather*}
> a_1: A\times A \to A\text{ such that }(x,y)\to x+y, \\
> a_2: A \to A\text{ such that }x\to -x
> \end{gather*}
> and $$a_3: A \to A\text{ such that }(x,y) \to x.y$$ are b-continuous where  $ A\times A$  carries product topology.

Where,

> A function $f:X \to Y$ from topological space $X$ to topological space $Y$ is said to be b-continuous (semi-continuous) if for each $x\in X$ and
> each open set $U \subset Y$ containing $f(x)$ there exists a b-open (semi-open) set $V \subset X$ containing $x$ such that $f(V) \subset U$.

> $\DeclareMathOperator\Int{Int}\DeclareMathOperator\cl{cl}$A set $B$ is called b-open if $B \subset \Int(\cl(B)) \cup \cl(\Int(B))$ and $S$ is semi-open if $S \subset \cl(\Int(S))$.

Clearly, topological rings $\implies$ semi-topological rings $\implies$ B-topological rings but not conversely.

After all these definitions I seek a B-topological ring that is not semi-topological. I already have other counterexamples but this one I have no idea about.

Comment: Definition $a_3$ is unclear. I presume you mean for each $a \in A$ the map $x \mapsto ax$ is continuous but not necessarily the map $(x,y) \mapsto xy$ is continuous.

Comment: Calling it a B-topological ring suggests we want $(x,y) \mapsto xy$ to be continuous. But that's not your definition. What you have defined looks more like a B-semitopological ring. Or a semi B-topological ring.

Comment: @Daron $a_3$ means jointly continuous.

Comment: Then your definitions are unclear. What is the domain of $a_3$?

Comment: And what in the world does semi-continuous mean?

Comment: I am sorry I meant jointly b- continuous. For semi, we mean jointly semicontinuous map.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the finite-complement topology on your favourite infinite set. The closure of every subset with interior is the whole space. That makes it easy for operation to be B-continuous. Now all you have to do is find operations that are not continuous.